# How to use strpos in PHP?

Tags: php

```
function check($text){
  if(strpos('a', $text) == FALSE && strpos('b', $text) == FALSE){
    echo 'error';
  } else {
    echo 'ok';
  }
}

echo check('text') . "\n";
echo check('asd') . "\n";
echo check('bnm') . "\n";
echo check('test') . "\n";
echo check('abc') . "\n";
```

live: http://codepad.org/W025YYuH

why this not working? This return:

> 1 error 2 error 3 error 4 error  5 error

but should be:

> 1 error 2 ok 3 ok 4 error  5 ok

Comment: Stropos returns position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invert the position of the argument, first argument is the string, second argument is what do you search into the string.

```
strpos ( 'The string to search in' ,'the argument of search' )
```

Then == would not work as expected
because the position of 'a' was the 0th (first) character.

Try this:

```
function check($text){
  if(strpos($text, 'a') === FALSE && strpos($text, 'b') === FALSE){
    echo 'error';
  } else {
    echo 'ok';
  }
}

echo check('text') . "\n";
echo check('asd') . "\n";
echo check('bnm') . "\n";
echo check('test') . "\n";
echo check('abc') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `=== FALSE` instead of `== FALSE`, as explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/strpos)

Additionally, your arguments are in the wrong order. Again, consult the documentation (or, as some people say, RTM)

Answer (score 1):

You have the arfuments the wrong way around, change to:

```
 if(strpos($text, 'a') === FALSE && strpos($text, 'b') === FALSE){
```

Also note that you need to check for a boolean `false` with the identical operator (===)